# How to write subquery like this using active records

Tags: codeigniter

Hello friends I wanna write this query in codeigniter using active record,

```
public function getHallServices($city,$receiption_capacity,$booked_date){
      $sql="select hi.*,hf.* FROM hall_info hi, hall_feature hf WHERE 
            hf.hall_info_id=hi.id and hi.city=? and hf.receiption_capacity<=? and hi.id not IN
            (select hall_info_id FROM events
              WHERE event_date = ? 
              GROUP BY hall_info_id
            )";
      $query=$this->db->query($sql,array('city'=>$city,'receiption_capacity'=>$receiption_capacity,'event_date'=>$booked_date));
      return $query->result_array(); 
    }
```

This query is not working as expected in codeigniter but works fine in postresql. I am not getting how to pass arguments to inner query. Please help me to correct or can give active record query for same.

Comment: You can check that : https://arjunphp.com/how-to-write-subqueries-in-codeigniter-active-record/

Answer (score 0):

Modify your codes to be like this:

```
public function getHallServices($city,$receiption_capacity,$booked_date){
  $sql="select hi.*,hf.* FROM hall_info hi, hall_feature hf WHERE 
        hf.hall_info_id=hi.id and hi.city=? and hf.receiption_capacity<=? and hi.id not IN
        (select hall_info_id FROM events
          WHERE event_date = ? 
          GROUP BY hall_info_id
        )";
  $query=$this->db->query($sql,array($city,$receiption_capacity,$booked_date));
  return $query->result_array(); 
}
```

Tell me if it works.